# How can a computer tell the difference between I and J?

Tags: resource-request, spelling, orthography, phonology

Most modern editions don't distinguish vocalic *I* from consonantal *J*. Most of the time, this doesn't create any real ambiguity.

However, for certain purposes it can be useful to know the difference: for example, when reading a passage out loud, or for composing metered poetry.

If I have a text that marks everything except *I* vs *J*, what's the best way to **automatically** determine the difference? My goal is a program that can go through and mark *J*s without human intervention—so it doesn't matter how complicated that system is, so long as it doesn't require specific human knowledge (so [Asteroides's otherwise-excellent suggestion](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/91/406) to look at English derivatives doesn't help me).

For a definite example: how can I know that *Jūlius* and *Troja* have a *J*, but *Iūlus* and *Gāius* have an *I*? Is there a reliable dictionary that lists this, for example, even in the case of proper names? Or is the best option to implement [Alex B's general rules](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1310/406) and not worry about the occasional error in a Greek loan?

(Bonus points if this can also recognize "hidden" *J*s before `/i/`, as in *e**j**iciō*.)

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14/406

Comment: I've always thought *Troia* was trisyllabic -- is this not the case?

Comment: Perhaps you should note that this is a subset of the question you asked yesterday https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14291/are-any-phonemic-distinctions-not-represented-in-latin

Comment: @CMonsour Related, but here I'm wondering if there's a way to distinguish them easily, there I'm wondering what distinctions exist. (I can delete this one if it's too similar though.)

Comment: Would it make sense to rephrase the question to ask for a method that recognizes when human judgement is needed and keeps those cases to a minimum (and maybe makes a reasonable guess if you want to run it independently)? I don't think the minimum will be zero unless you get close to a full dictionary approach.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yeah, I doubt I'll be able to get 100% accuracy, but anything that minimizes the human intervention required would be helpful.

Comment: @Draconis I don't think you should delete this.  But a cross-reference would be nice.  (from that one to this one).

Comment: Also related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13265/406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This already exists. At http://alatius.com/macronizer you can tick the option "convert i into j" (as well as "u into v"). It works most of the time, but I don't know how. It probably checks a list of exceptions before it applies some general rules.

Comment: It might be worth adding that [the source is available](https://github.com/Alatius/latin-macronizer), as well.

Comment: @Draconis It looks like it just has a major master list!